# Event handling issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I have a very basic code that just won't work on Firefox, but works fine on Chrome. I just want to trigger a function when the user clicks anywhere in the page. Here is the code:

```
window.onload = function(){
 alert(document.body);   // Is executed correctly
 document.body.onclick = function(){
       /*do stuff*/
  }
}
```

and it works just fine on Chrome but not on Firefox. I tried many workarounds but none of them work, and there is no error in the error console.

```
  function set(){
       /*do stuff*/
  }
 document.body.onclick = set;
```

or

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',set,false);
```

I am trying with a very basic html page with just

```
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

None of them work. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that code in the `<head>`? If it is, the body doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Where in your HTML code do you have the JavaScript code?

Comment: @bfavaretto The code is indeed in the head, but all of the JavaScript is triggered after the "window.onload" event. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Where are you clicking? It should work if you click the h1 (which is within the body's `offsetHeight`). If you want the whole viewport to be clickable, use `document.onclick`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks. I wasn't clicking on the h1. It works now. I'm still wondering why it worked on Chrome though.

Comment: For me both Chrome and FF are behaving the same way. Weird.

Comment: @André Chrome incorrectly sizes the body of HTML documents in quirks mode to fill the whole viewport.  Was your document in quirks mode?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky I kept the default settings.

Comment: @André That doesn't answer my question.  Does the page have a doctype declaration or not?  If it does, which one?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky It has the default HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Odd.  `<!DOCTYPE html><body style="border: 1px solid green"><script>document.body.onclick = function() {alert('clicked');</script>Click me</body>` doesn't alert for me if I click outside the body (the green box) in Chrome.

Comment: Odd indeed. Anyway the issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are binding onclick event after the html page has loaded?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function (){
  document.body.onclick = function() { alert("Hi");};
});
```

This works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.